# PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am getting this error :

o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

when I try to render a view from an controller/action

I've read about it being that servlet mapping being:

Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet
/webspring/*

and the star hijacks even the jsp renderings. How can I overcome this ( as simple as possible ) and hopefully without having to resort to .do endings so it becomes controller/action.do

Thanks !

**===============EDIT=================**

It appears that this happens if your jsp is not in the WEB-INF folder, but outside but in WebContent... any idea why? The jsp's cant be outside? Or shouldnt?

But now I still have problems with linking to a css file... which usually are outside of the web-inf directory, right?

A link:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="webspring/public/main.css" type="text/css"/>
```

where the directory structure is:

> - WebContent
> - WEB-INF
> - webspring
>
>   - public
>
>     main.css

...  is being resolved to

**http://localhost:8080/XXXWeb/webspring/auth**/webspring/public/main.css

when the **style tag is added** on page with  url:

**http://localhost:8080/XXXWeb/webspring**/auth/loginForm

**auth** is the controller.

What is going on here?

Comment: It appears that this happens if your jsp is not in the WEB-INF folder, but outside but in WebContent... any idea why? The jsp's cant be outside? Or shouldnt? 

Thanks!

Comment: can you show me your deployment descriptor file for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with you. So I resolve like this

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webspring/auth/webspring/public/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```